# Oracle Sql Extract ID based on grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some ID  and Flag, I want output only those ID whose ID flag is Valid.
Before taking valid, there are some preconditions:

- One ID will be appear max 2 times and min 1 time.
- If one id is appearing 2 times and having flag both valid / invalid, then we need to exclude those IDs.
- If one ID having a single invalid flag, then it also needs to be exclude.
- If one Single ID only having Valid that records it should include.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Get all ID's where count is 1 and less than 2 and have only 1 distinct flag. Hence in subquery: `HAVING COUNT(*)<=2 AND COUNT (DISTINCT Flag)=1`

Satisfy condition 1 and 4 and help us to satisfy condition 2,3

2.Then I am checking that none of these flag should be "INVALID"
Hence in where clause `AND Flag = 'Valid'`
Satisfy condition 2,3

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE ID IN (
                SELECT ID
                FROM T
                GROUP BY ID
                HAVING COUNT(*)<=2 AND COUNT (DISTINCT Flag)=1)
AND Flag = 'Valid'
```